# Procedimiento almacenado que contiene dos insert no me regresa las variables de salida

Tags: php, php8, magento

Este procedimiento lo ejecuto con PDO en mi php el codigo es el siguiente

```php
$sql = 
     '
        EXEC xpQARNCGeneraPedidoWebC
                                    "'.$IDE.'",
                                    "'.$Direccion.'",
                                    "'.$DireccionNumero.'",
                                    "0",
                                    "'.$Delegacion.'",
                                    "'.$Colonia.'",
                                    "Verificar",
                                    "'.$Ciudad.'",
                                    "'.$Estado.'",
                                    "México",
                                    "'.$CP.'",
                                    "'.$EntreCalles.'",
                                    "'.$Nombre.'",
                                    "'.$Telefono.'"
                            ';
                            $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);                
                            $stmt->execute();
                            $query = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Cuando llega al `fetchAll` o `fetch` me muestra este error

> "SQLSTATE[24000]: Invalid cursor state: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for
> SQL Server]Invalid cursor state (SQLFetchScroll[0] at
> ext\pdo_odbc\odbc_stmt.c:547)"

Ojo, si el procedimiento solo contiene puros `select` funciona, cuando tiene un `insert` muestra ese error